# Adding libraries in Eclipse JAVA with MAC OS

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to add External libraries of Asprise OCR 
in Eclipse IDE with mac os and want to run a program

Answer (score 2):

`Select a project > (menu) Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARs`

Comment: it gives an run time error ....................
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no AspriseOCR in java.library.path...
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1809)..
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)...
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)...
 at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.loadLibrary(OCR.java:247)...
 at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.<init>(OCR.java:56)...
 at Demo.main(Demo.java:18)...

Comment: You need a native library attached to the jar file.  Have a VERY good look on the properties panel for the Jar file.

Comment: I have added aspriseOcr.jar file in java.library.path..after that..it gives an another error like that..Exception in thread "main"..java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:/Library/Java/Extensions/libAspriseOCR.jnilib:  no suitable image found..Didfind:/Library/Java/Extensions/libAspriseOCR.jnilib: mach-o, but wrong architecture..at .........

Comment: I have given the path of native library ie libAspriseOCR.jnlib

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be building your Java project using Maven. You only need to add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.asprise.ocr</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-ocr-api</artifactId>
    <version>[15,)</version>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively, you can manually download the [Java OCR library (jar) here](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/java-ocr-for-windows-mac-linux-download.html).